# writing a rule to get string from div to use in link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to build a rule on "Sponsored products related to this item" on Amazon,however, the  ASIN for each product is embedded in xpath `//ol/li/div/@data-asin` from which I want to produce the following link format `f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{ASIN}` (for each item in Sponsored products related to this item)

```
scrapy shell https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PB5M8DS


from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
#Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//ol[@class="a-carousel"]/li/div',process_value= lambda i: f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{i}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy's `LinkExtractor` only knows how to extract links in a specific way.
If you want to construct your own links, you'll have to write your own link extractor.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.link import Link


class ASINLinkExtractor:
    def extract_links(self, response):
        asins = response.xpath('//ol/li/div/@data-asin').getall()
        for asin in asins:
            yield Link(f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}')
```

Then you'd just use `ASINLinkExtractor()` inside the rule instead of using the one provided by scrapy.

Comment: does this extract_links interfere with scrapy `LinkExtractor` builtin method?

Comment: No, it's just a method of a different class that's named the same in order to implement the expected api.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it without using `Rule` and `LinkExtractor`. You have to override `parse` method from `CrawlSpider` in your spider.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        yield from super().parse(response)

        asins = response.xpath('//ol/li/div/@data-asin').getall()
        for asin in asins:
            url = f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}'
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```